# DependencyResolver: Pass parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I use autofac and can pass parameters to my resolve method.

How can I do this using microsofts DependencyResolver interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IDependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) does not support passing parameters directly, as I'm sure you have noticed. However, since you have Autofac under the hood, you're able to resolve a factory delegate that enables you to pass on parameters to the underlying service:

```
var factory = dependencyResolver.GetService<Func<int, string, IService>>();
var service = factory(5, "42");
```

Note: you can either use `Func` delegates or explicitly defined factory delegates. More on this [here](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories).

Regarding lifetime scopes: factory delegates must be resolved from a scope where the requested service can be "reached". Consider this setup simulating how MVC or WebApi would look like:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<X>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("http");
var application = cb.Build();
var request = application.BeginLifetimeScope("http");
```

With this setup, our `X` service will only be available in the http scope. Trying to resolve `X` from `application` scope will fail with this message:

> No scope with a Tag matching 'http' is visible from the scope 
>       in which the instance was requested.

Resolving from the `request` scope will work as expected:

```
var f = request.Resolve<Func<IX>>();
var x = f();
```

Comment: This seems to be a good idea but will this work if I use different contexts? The objcts should be registered as .InstancePerHttpRequest(); or .InstancePerApiRequest();

Comment: @user437899 - added some input around lifetime scopes. Hope it clarifies :)

Answer (score 0):

The general advice is to resolve a factory. Either you define a custom factory interface for the type you need to resolve (this has my preference), or resolve a delegate (which is what Peter Lillevold suggests). Either way, you should not call the container (or `DependencyResolver` for that matter) directly, since this is [sub optimal](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).